# C26486 - Don't pass a pointer that may be invalid to a function?

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-warnings

I'm developing a kernel driver for Windows and I recently decided to transition from C to C/C++. During my code transformation, I encounter a warning that I can't solve. Basically, I have a function with this particular line of code:

```
OB_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS
OCPreOperationCallback(
    _In_ PVOID RegistrationContext,
    _Inout_ POB_PRE_OPERATION_INFORMATION OperationInformation
    )
{
    // ...
    auto test = IoThreadToProcess(static_cast<PETHREAD>(OperationInformation->Object));
    // ...
}
```

This line is highlited with the error message as follows:

> Warning   C26486  Don't pass a pointer that may be invalid to a function. Parameter 0 '(*OperationInformation).Object' in call to 'IoThreadToProcess' may be invalid (lifetime.3).

The warning seems pretty clear: I need to make sure the pointer I pass as an argument is valid. Nevertheless, I could not find any way to check for an invalid state. I tried to add:

```
if(OperationInformation != nullptr && OperationInformation->Object != nullptr)
```

before the assignment, but the warning is still present.

Did I miss something regarding this issue ?

Comment: Not familiar with this, but what happens when you check the `static_cast<PETHREAD>` result for null-ness instead?

Comment: It seems the static analysis in newer Visual Studio versions has become overly aggressive; there have been quite a few questions about false positives recently. I suspect this could be one of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
PETHREAD pThread = static_cast<PETHREAD>(OperationInformation->Object);
if(pThread != nullptr) //or 'pThread != NULL' or 'pThread'
{
   auto test = IoThreadToProcess(pThread);
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately, it seems the warning is still issued with your example: https://imgur.com/6NOGwWD.